# AlertDialog Buttons Reverse Order With alertDialogStyle Item

Tags: java, android, android-alertdialog

I'm creating a custom theme for a standard alert dialog box, and after I add the `alertDialogStyle` item, the OK/Cancel buttons on the alert box reverse in order.  I expect Cancel first, then OK.  It works without the `alertDialogStyle item`, but as soon as I add the item, the buttons show OK and Cancel.

```xml
<!-- create style for Simple Alert Dialog Box -->
<style name="simpleDialogBoxStyle" parent="AppDialogTheme">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/dialog_actvity_border</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/standard_text_color_BLACK</item>
    <item name="android:textAppearanceMedium">@style/AlertDialogBodyAttributes</item>
    <item name="android:textAppearanceLarge">@style/AlertDialogTitleAttributes</item>
    <item name="android:textAppearanceButton">@style/AlertDialogButtonAttributes</item>
    <item name="android:buttonBarButtonStyle">@style/AlertDialogButtonAttributes</item>
    <item name="android:alertDialogStyle">@style/AlertDialogColors</item>
</style>

<style name="AlertDialogColors">
    <item name="android:bottomBright">@color/custom_theme_color</item>
    <item name="android:bottomMedium">@color/custom_theme_color</item>
    <item name="android:centerBright">@color/custom_theme_color</item>
    <item name="android:centerDark">@color/custom_theme_color</item>
    <item name="android:centerMedium">@color/custom_theme_color</item>
    <item name="android:fullBright">@color/custom_theme_color</item>
    <item name="android:fullDark">@color/custom_theme_color</item>
    <item name="android:topBright">@color/custom_theme_color</item>
    <item name="android:topDark">@color/custom_theme_color</item>
</style>

<style name="AlertDialogBodyAttributes">
    <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/default_text_size_medium</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/standard_text_color_BLACK</item>
</style>

<style name="AlertDialogTitleAttributes">
    <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/default_text_size_medium</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/standard_text_color_BLACK</item>
</style>

<style name="AlertDialogButtonAttributes" >
    <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/default_text_size</item>
    <item name="android:textAllCaps">true</item>
    <item name="android:background">@color/transparent_color</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
 </style>
```

Here is the method to show the Alert box with OK/Cancel:

```java
public static void ShowOKCancelMessageBox(Context context, int  xmlRLayout, String msg, String title, DialogInterface.OnClickListener listener) {

    AlertDialog.Builder dlgAlert = new AlertDialog.Builder(context, xmlRLayout);
    dlgAlert.setMessage(msg);
    dlgAlert.setTitle(title);
    dlgAlert.setPositiveButton("OK", listener);
    dlgAlert.setNegativeButton("Cancel", listener);
    dlgAlert.setCancelable(false);
    dlgAlert.create().show();
}
```